# extract PDO error message

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried getting error message on connection in PDO but it returns 
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'aa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` . along with code and SQLSTATE part. Is there a way to get only  `Access denied for user 'aa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` part ?

How can i extract part after [1045] so that i can print only error part or error? I'm using:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());

}
```

**Thanks guys i found my answer**

Comment: What's the point in getting only part of the message? What you're going to do with it? Why not just let it be logged as any other error message?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I want to show my users what are they doing wrong like if mistake is in username, dbname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    if(strstr($e->getMessage(), 'SQLSTATE[')) {
            preg_match('/SQLSTATE\[(\w+)\] \[(\w+)\] (.*)/', $e->getMessage(), $matches);
           var_dump($matches);
        }
```

at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php#97908

Answer (score 2):

using errorinfo
try :

```
$errorInfo= $db->errorInfo();
$msg= $errorInfo[2];
```

PDO::errorInfo() returns an array of error information about the last operation performed by this database handle. The array consists of the following fields:

Element Information
0   SQLSTATE error code (a five characters alphanumeric identifier defined in the ANSI SQL standard).
1   Driver-specific error code.
2   Driver-specific error message.

source :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php